# Persistence Layer In SaaS Application

Tags: relational-database, saas, nosql

I have planned a SaaS Application for which we have selected Java for building the back end ,not yet selected which frameworks to utilize and I have opted to use either Ember JS with Bootstrap or Foundation with Bootstrap or Angular JS with Bootstrap for building the front end of the application.

I am confused with the persistence layer that either I should go for traditional Relational databases or should I go for 'Nosql Database' .

The idea is simple and straight ,offering Highly Configurable School Management System in SaaS model.The module at first I will be working on is Time and Attendance tracking of School/Universities/Colleges/Coaching Centers etc.As you can see that the policy of attendance (late,absent,present) varies from school to school ,university to university ,within university department to department ,within department teacher to teacher ,and coaching to coaching etc .And our application is not going to be deployed to their respective servers and will be hosted at cloud so one application running Accommodating dynamic policies running in isolation from the other.

My data is expected to grow with the period of time ,at fast pace since every school/coaching/institute will contain data of the following and following entities will be using the Application,Parent ,Student,Teachers,Principles,person who wants to take admission,Peons,etc

I have read answers to questions posted for the same kind of query and I found that people have used relational databases for this kind of application but they have built it 5-10 years back when there was no concept of Nosql databases ,All we knew was relational,object oriented databases so it would not be wrong to say that they opt the stack that was available at that time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should go for relational databases and I don't see any need of using Nosql databases ,the schema you will be having is static I am sure and you will be needed to maintain complex relationships as well.
Have a look at 'Multi tenant Architecture' ,and I would suggest you to use one database per client against one db per all clients.
Lets see what others would recommend you.